# Trying to pop-up window so I can insert quantity of products needed while dragging from one table to another

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, pyqt5, popup

Currently, I'm working on the WMS project.

I'm trying to a pop-up window after I dragged the product from the left Table(Table Show) to the right Table(Table Order) where I can enter the amount needed so that values in TableCells(Quantity_Columns) are changed respectively.

[image: App]

**Here is a code:**

```
class TableWidgetDragRows(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setDragEnabled(False)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)
        # self.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)

        self.last_drop_row = None

    # Override this method to get the correct row index for insertion
    def dropMimeData(self, row, col, mimeData, action):
        self.last_drop_row = row
        return True

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        # The QTableWidget from which selected rows will be moved
        sender = event.source()

        # Default dropEvent method fires dropMimeData with appropriate parameters (we're interested in the row index).
        super().dropEvent(event)
        # Now we know where to insert selected row(s)
        dropRow = self.last_drop_row

        selectedRows = sender.getselectedRowsFast()

        # Allocate space for transfer
        for _ in selectedRows:
            self.insertRow(dropRow)
            
        # if sender == receiver (self), after creating new empty rows selected rows might change their locations
        sel_rows_offsets = [0 if self != sender or srow < dropRow else len(selectedRows) for srow in selectedRows]
        selectedRows = [row + offset for row, offset in zip(selectedRows, sel_rows_offsets)]
  
        ------------------------------------------------------
        | ** YOUR SUGGESTIONS ON IMPLEMENTING SOLUTION HERE**|
        ------------------------------------------------------


        # copy content of selected rows into empty ones
        for i, srow in enumerate(selectedRows):
            for j in range(self.columnCount()):
                item = sender.item(srow, j)
                if item:
                    source = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(item)
                    self.setItem(dropRow + i, j, source)
    
        event.accept()

    def getselectedRowsFast(self):
        selectedRows = []
        for item in self.selectedItems():
            if item.row() not in selectedRows:
                selectedRows.append(item.row())
        selectedRows.sort()
        return selectedRows
```

[image]

Comment: 1) how should the amounts change ?, 2) provide a [mre]

Comment: 1)After drag action is done(from the left to the right table) I need to be able to input the number into the pop-up window so that data in the left table(quantity of product) will be subtracted according to the inputted data and on the right table actual inputted data will be shown.
2) I can not provide a minimal reproducible example as I don't really know how to do it, so I'm asking for help, however, I can provide pictures.